# React используя useQuery не могу обновить сразу два запроса

Tags: reactjs, typescript, nestjs

У меня есть две константы, в которые сохраняются данные с сервера. При клике по одному элементу мне нужно обновить первый запрос, при клике по другому - второй.

Но метод refetch можно установить только один раз.

Что я делаю не так?

```js
const {
    data: studentGroup,
    refetch
} = useQuery({
    queryKey: ['studGroup'],
    queryFn: () => studentsApi.getByGroup < IStudentEmployment[] > ({
        groupId: select
    })
}) const {
    data: employment,
    refetch
} = useQuery({
    queryKey: ['studSpec'],
    queryFn: () => employmentApi.getByStudID < IEmployment[] > ({
        studentID: student
    })
})
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: const {data: studentGroup, refetch} = useQuery({queryKey: ['studGroup'], queryFn: () => studentsApi.getByGroup<IStudentEmployment[]>({groupId:select})})
    const {data: employment, refetch} = useQuery({queryKey: ['studSpec'], queryFn: () => employmentApi.getByStudID<IEmployment[]>({studentID:student})})

Comment: Добавьте этот код в вопрос, нажав на кнопку "править", а не текстом в комментарии.